# Specifying routing from nested module Angular 2 via NPM package

Tags: angular, npm, routes, nested, angular2-routing

I have been trying to build an angular 2 application. 
I have got this basic structure.

AppModule

- AppComponent
- App.Routing
- App.template
- App.module

I have another module let's say 'SampleModule' as an NPM package which I am loading and importing in App.module file

My problem now is to specify one of the routes in the App routing to point to a component inside 'SampleModule' let's say 'SampleComponent'.

I have tried exposing the component from the SampleModule and I have tried importing here in the App routing. It didn't work. It says, can't find the name SampleComponent

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: can you provide your code??.

Answer (score 1):

Since 'SampleModule' is an npm package, the files of 'SampleModule' can be found under the node_modules folder(project root path).

First export the SampleComponet by adding following lines to SampleModule

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [SampleComponet],
  exports: [SampleComponet] <== this line
})
export class SampleModule{}
```

Then in your App.module, Import the 'SampleModule'

```
import { SampleModule } from '/path_to_node_modules/path_to_sample_module/';

@NgModule({
  imports: [SampleModule],<== this line
})
export class AppModule{}
```

Now you can import the 'SampleComponent' directly to your App.Routing by following import statement

```
import { SampleComponent } from '/path_to_node_modules/path_to_componet/';

{ path: 'sample', component: SampleComponent }
```

Note: If the SampleModule has its own routing and it is defined as below

```
const routes: Routes = [~routings~]

    @NgModule({
      imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
      declarations: [SampleComponet],
      exports: [SampleComponet] <== this line
    })
    export class SampleModule{}
```

then use the following code in your App router

```
{
    path: 'sample',
    loadChildren: './path_to_node_modules/path_to_sample_module/sample.module#SampleModule'
}
```